# Java - Change the value in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that like this:  `HashMap<UUID, CustomClass>`.

CustomClass has a lot of properties that make it meaningfully unique.  I need to be able to update the value of a key already in the map with a new instance of CustomClass.  Then I need to call a method called "CustomClass.clearInfo()" that clears/nulls/zeros out the values of all the properties accordingly.

The problem is the "Put" method just changes the reference of the value to refer to the new instance, so when I call clearInfo(), the hashed value is also cleared.

I need to keep the values before the call to clearInfo().

Comment: I can't understand the question. Post code, tell us what you expect it to be, and what it does instead. The hash of the CustomClass is irrelevant, since it isn't used as the key of the map.

Comment: Let me simplify the question.  How do I do a deep copy in Java without having to use a copy constructor or having to set every property individually?

Comment: @BladeHal How do you make a deep copy, if you do not set every property individually?

Comment: I'm asking is there any method in the Java framework that does this without having to manually do it?

Comment: @BladeHal Not in the Java System Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the object using the `HashMap.remove(key)` method. Then you can put a new object in the key you have just removed.

See the documentation for [`remove()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Notice the return type of `remove(K key)`. With this you could write: `hashMap.remove(oldKey).clearInfo(); hashMap.put(newKey, newCustomClass);`